# How can I enumerate the available KMS modes using open syscall?

Tags: display-resolution, kms

I’m trying to install some vGPU platform and I found the resolution is somehow locked, xrandr didn’t work, it returns “ Failed to get size of gamma”.

So I’m thinking maybe I can enumerate the available KMS modes if I can read from the KMS file descriptor using the open syscall.

By I’m not sure how to practice this.
Can anyone tell me how I can access the KMS file descriptor, and enumerate the KMS modes?

Comment: The `fbset` utility can do that. I've tried finding a manual page describing the ioctls, but couldn't find one immediately.

Comment: @SimonRichter I tried “fbset -g 1920 1080 1920 1080 32”, the command ran without error, but nothing on my screen seems changed, what have I done wrong?